# WooCommerce: change the add to cart text when the product is already in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I am having an issue changing the text of the *"Add to cart"* button in WooCommerce/WordPress.

Currently the code below, I want it so that if a product is already in cart, the *"Add to cart"* button reflects that by changing the text to state it's already in the cart.

At the moment, it remains *"Add to cart"* even if product is in cart. What is strange is if I remove the if condition, the text changes, so I am assuming there's something wrong with the if condition but I can't see any issue with it.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_text');
function woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_text($add_to_cart_text, $product_id) {
    global $woocommerce;
    
    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {
        $_product = $val['data'];
 
        if($product_id == $_product->id ) {
            $add_to_cart_text = 'Already in cart';
        }
        
    return $add_to_cart_text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$_product->id` should be `$_product->get_id()`
- Use `return` outside the foreach loop
- global `$woocommerce` is not necessary
- Second parameter from `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text` filter hook is `$product`, not `$product_id`

So you get

```php
function woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_text( $add_to_cart_text, $product ) {
    // Get cart
    $cart = WC()->cart;
    
    // If cart is NOT empty
    if ( ! $cart->is_empty() ) {

        // Iterating though each cart items
        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            // Get product id in cart
            $_product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
     
            // Compare 
            if ( $product->get_id() == $_product_id ) {
                // Change text
                $add_to_cart_text = __( 'Already in cart', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $add_to_cart_text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Is this piece of code applicable in the latest Woocommerce as of today?